# Dockerfile , docker-compose.yml and application.properties confusion

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I am developing a Spring Boot app and want to keep the database on a Docker container. However, after making a search and try to install the databse and connect,  I am really very confused with `docker-compose.yml`, `Dockerfile` and `application.properties` in the app. Could you please clarify me shortly about the following points?

**1.** AS far as I see, `docker-compose.yml` is used to create Docker containers e.g. creating a database container on Docker. If we do not run it via `docker-compose up -d`, `docker-compose.yml` is not executed ehen we run the Spring Boot app. Is that true?

**2.** When `Dockerfile` is executed? As it is used to build necessary images for our apps, I think it is used for publishing phase. Is that true?

**3.** As far as I see, we use database connection string in our `application.properties` (or yml version) and when we run the app, it is used. Is the difference between `application.properties` and `docker-compose.yml`, the former is executed when app is running and the latter is used only we execute. Is that true?

I have the following but although the table creation string is seen on the console after app is run, it cannot create table (I have @Entity and @Repository annotations for the related entity in my app). So, what is the problem?

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/product_db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=********

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = public
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

***Update:*** Here is the log message on the console indicating that the product table is creating, etc.

> Hibernate: drop table if exists public.product cascade
>
> Hibernate: create table public.product (id bigserial not null, name varchar(255), code varchar(255), primary key (id))

Comment: Can you please add the error message you get..??

Comment: @BALAJIVS I have no error message, just the sql command for table creation. I added it to update.

Answer (score 1):

1. In fact, the `docker-compose.yml` file is only used by `docker-compose up` and other `docker-compose` commands.  Plain `docker` commands and non-Docker `java` commands don't look at it at all.
2. The `Dockerfile` is read when you run `docker-compose build`, or `docker-compose up --build`, or `docker build`.  There are also Maven and Gradle extensions to build Docker images.  It needs to run before you can run a container, for example for manual or integration testing.  Note that most settings in the `docker-compose.yml` file are not visible in the Dockerfile, and the image build can't access other containers.
3. Spring has several ways to set properties.  Note that things like the database URL will be different running in a container vs. running directly on the host, and could be different again in a cloud environment; that makes this something that's inappropriate to set in an `application.properties` file built into the jar file.  You can set a `$SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment variable in your `docker-compose.yml` instead.

So a typical Compose setup for what you've shown above might look something like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  application:
    build: .             # `docker-compose up --build` will read the Dockerfile
    ports: ['8080:8080'] # host:container port
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db/product_db
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=********
  db:
    image: postgres:14   # from Docker Hub, not built locally
    ports: ['5432:5432'] # optional
    volumes:             # persist database data across restarts
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=product_db 
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=********
volumes:
  dbdata:                # no particular settings for this volume
```

The `SPRING_DATASOURCE_*` environment variables set the corresponding `spring.datasource.*` properties and override the `application.properties` file.

Comment: **1.** `docker-compose.yml` is executed by commands for creating docker container and all the necessary config info for installations on this container e.g. database, ports, volume, username, password... Is that true?

Comment: **2.** Is `Dockerfile` is much more related to running the app on a container and installation all the necessary programs that is needed the app runs. But I am not sure when it is executed. Could you give a basic scenario?

Comment: **3.** `application.properties` or `application.yml` contains all the necessary configs that our app needs. Is there anything special for this file?

Comment: You might ask these in a separate question, or even several; it seems like they cover a lot of ground, more than could reasonably be answered in comments.  I will say that you generally should not install software outside of a Dockerfile.

Comment: Ok, I created a new question. What about [Docker: Understanding Dockerfile vs docker-compose.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71459001/docker-understanding-dockerfile-vs-docker-compose-yml) ? Any help please? Regards.